# Total of Multiple COUNT SELECTS from the multiple tables not working

Tags: sql, count, group-by

I have A attendance report in which I want to show report day wise like  this :

[image]

I can calculate Sum individually , But not the total of all Sum

My StudentAttendance Table :

```
ID  ClassID SubjectID Day10 Day11   Day12   Day13   Day14   Day15         ProfessorID   
215     23    46                                        P                        36                                             36   
216     23    47                                        P                        36  
217     23    48                                        P                        36                                                   P                                                                     36   
218     17    35                                        P                        28
```

I have Tried this Query :

```
select ClassID,
    sum(case when Day14= 'P' then 1 else 0 end) Present,
    sum(case when Day14= 'A' then 1 else 0 end) Absent,
    sum(case when Day14= 'L' then 1 else 0 end) Leave
from studentattendance 
group by ClassID,Day14
```

I tried Sum(Present.Absent,Leave)..But not working What  I am missing ??

Comment: Usually is better if you tell us what isnt working. Probaly a desire output will help a lot. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please read this line in post ...".I can calculate Sum individually , But not the total of all Sum"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no SQL syntax for a `SELECT` with multiple `FROM` clauses(WITHOUT nesting).
Perhaps you want something like this?

```
select 
  classID,
  count(Day14) Total,
  sum(case when Day14='P' then 1 else 0 end) Present,
  sum(case when Day14='A' then 1 else 0 end) Absent,
  sum(case when Day14='L' then 1 else 0 end) Leave   
from studentattendance
group by classID
```

Here `Total` is merely the total number of records in each `classID`. The `sum(case..when..)` statements simulates a selective `count()` only when certain condition is satisfied (`Day14` is either Present,Absent or Leave). Note that there is no guarantee that the `Total` to be equal to `Present+Absent+Leave` if you expect values other than these 3 to be present in the column `Day14`

Comment: Yes , Offcourse , small issue .Sometime looks bigger under pressure.. :)....Thanks a lot